# Should I use http protocol in my server for an android/web app

Tags: java, android, web-services, servlets

I am planning to write an application which will include use of a server which will get requests from possibly mobile phones, and sometimes MAYBE web browsers. I am trying to get together the technologies I would like to use. However I am confused at the part about my server.

Let's say I have a mobile app, which will need to ask my server for login authentication and other stuff. And this system will also be available for browsers through a web page. The logical thing to do would be for them to share the same server for the start right ? Maybe even same application on the server side ?

I am confused if there are other protocols than http t hat I should use for my server, regarding the requests from mobile app. Or http is a good and viable choice for any application on any device ?

I hope my question is clear enough. I am looking forward to your replies.

Thank you.

**EDIT :** My main concern is for the protocol I would need to use for a desktop / mobile app which DO NOT USE a browser. As I mentioned, the browser is only a maybe, an addition t hat could possibly use the same application in the server side for the same information needed.

Comment: I would suggest you to divide the system from view (WebPage/App) and a REST-Backend-API.

Comment: I see, but I dont see how that answers my question regarding the protocol : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the server should be accessed via HTTP protocol unless there are reason to use a different protocol. Typically the server is accessed via a RESTFul endpoint and the content-type is application/json (as opposed to a SOAP endpoint and application/xml content-type).

Server endpoints for mobile app may be different from the server endpoint for browser or desktop client, or it may be the same endpoint that supports query options to account for special considerations of mobile clients.

Answer (score 0):

Writing it as a **web based application delivered over http** would mean that first of all web browsers would be able to connect to it, and if you write it in a **responsive** way then it can look good for mobile browser too.

You can then build a **REST** or **SOAP** service on top which would work well for mobile application. Note that your choice of which one depends on a range of factors specific to your use case. This link will go into a lot of detail as to the pros and cons of each approach:

http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hello, as i mentioned in my question, "browser" is only a MAYBE. My main aim and concern is of an application server's protocol. Imagine my app as an android or ios app, not a web site. You could even imagine it as a desktop application for pc which uses internet to work.